# unable to get access token from OAuth 2.0 Authorization Code Flow

Tags: oauth-2.0, openid, azure-active-directory, openid-connect, adal

I am trying to implement [OAuth 2.0 Authorization Code Flow](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/active-directory-v2-protocols-oauth-code/) in a multi-tenant application.

I first requested authorization for **"openid profile email"** scope at `login.microsoftonline.com/organizations/oauth2/v2.0/authorize` 
and then used the code I obtained along with 
`grant_type=authorization_code`, **client_id**, **client_secret**, **redirect_uri** for an access token at `login.microsoftonline.com/organizations/oauth2/v2.0/token`

The response I got contained only `id_token`, and `token_type=Bearer`.  Why wasn't I given the `access_token` and `expired_at` fields?

I tried to provide the scope again at the token call but the response came back the same.  The [spec](http://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-core-1_0.html#TokenResponse) says it should contain the access token.  I also tried /common endpoints but things are the same.

Comment: The bearer token is the access token.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the Azure AD v2.0 endpoint. You can tell this by the fact that your url has *v2.0* in it.

In the v2.0 endpoint, if you only ask for scopes that are contained in the id_token (i.e. openid profile email) and don't ask for any other scopes (i.e. https://outlook.office.com/contacts.read) you will only get back an id_token. This due to the fact that you're basically telling Azure AD that you only want profile info and aren't talking to any apis, therefore won't need an access token.

On the other hand, if you include a scope for an api (i.e. https://outlook.office.com/contacts.read) you'll get back an access_code.

Comment: I wanted to access Discovery API and Drop Box for Business API, but it seems neither are supported in the v2.0 endpoint from https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/active-directory-v2-limitations/  Looks like I have to use the v1.0 endpoint instead.